# Convertir metros a kilometros

Tags: javascript

Quiero convertir 1000708 metros  a   1,000.708 km

este es mi codigo:

```
let decimalFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 2 });

let result = decimalFormat.format(1000708 / 1000);

result = 1000,71
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este caso, lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Es importante mencionar que en este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos, es necesario mostrar el código que llevas hasta el momento para poderte ayudar.

Answer (score 3):

Ya casi lo tenias, tan solo mirando la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) de `Intl.NumberFormat` hubieras visto muchos ejemplos parecidos a este:

```js
numero = 1000708 / 1000
let result = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format(numero);
console.log(result + ' km')
```